# Intellij 13 with sbt 13.1 unable to resolve global-plugins where no global plugins exist

Tags: scala, plugins, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-13

I have an scala project built with sbt that I am attempting to import into IntelliJ13.

Scala 2.10.3 with sbt 13.1, scala plugin installed and up to date. Running on Fedora20 w/Oracle JDK7.  Project builds and runs without issue from the command line.  However, when I attempt to import the project into IntelliJ the import fails since plugin default#global-plugins;0.0 cannot be resolved.

I have no actual global plugins installed under ~/.sbt/0.13.

The entire project has no reference in the config or otherwise to the word `global`.

I am new to both Scala and sbt so forgive if I have left out necessary details.  However, as I said there is no reference anywhere to a plugin named anything even close to "global" and there are no global plugins configured.  The resulting error from the logs is as follows:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: default#global-plugins;0.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      default:global-plugins:0.0 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn] 
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: default#global-plugins;0.0: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:60)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:101)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:97)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1144)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1142)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1165)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1163)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1167)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1162)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1170)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1135)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1113)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: default#global-plugins;0.0: not found

    at org.jetbrains.sbt.project.SbtProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(SbtProjectResolver.scala:31)
    at org.jetbrains.sbt.project.SbtProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(SbtProjectResolver.scala:19)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    ... 21 more
```

I have searched about and have not found anyone encountering this exact fail to resolve error - has anyone else encountered this or have any idea as to why it might be happening?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this error but at the command line rather than in IntelliJ. I was eventually able to resolve it by doing an rm -rf on the following directories

```
target
project/target
project/project/target
~/.sbt/
~/.ivy2/
```

I had other complicating factors,

- I'd just upgraded to the latest https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras
- I also tried upgrading to 0.13.1 to 0.13.2 in my project/build.properties
- We block all access to external repos and push everything through our internal Artifactory (I was also able to make the problem go away by turning this off - so your problems could also be network related.)

Answer (score 0):

I found adding an empty folder at `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins` worked.

**Edit:** This didn't work for me when I hit the issue again. My way around this this time was to download the zip [directly](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html) and aliased `sbt` to point to the executable (putting it on my PATH left me with the same error!!)

This would indicate there is some other config somewhere that `sbt` isn't happy with but I decided not to go down the rabbit hole of finding out where that lives :)